Losing reputation points when I didn't even post anything
I stumbled into a log of my reputation changes and noticed something strange:  there were several -1 entries where I neither answered the question nor made any comments.  I searched thoroughly and for one of these read everything from top to bottom and couldn't even find my name mentioned, so I am more than a bit baffled.
I figure either I'm really missing something, or something weird is going on, so rather than keep trying I decided to ask, and Meta seemed the only place I could do that.

Downvoting answers costs 1 rep point.
